# JS fetch to Python request

Tags: javascript, python, python-requests

I am trying to use an API but all the examples are in JS, and my project is in python.

Here is the sample code they gave me:

```js
const request = await fetch("https://api.tiktokenizer.dev/openai", {
  headers: { Authorization: "Bearer <OPENAI_API_KEY>" },
  method: "POST",
  body: JSON.stringify({
    email: "<APP_USER_EMAIL>",
    appId: "<APPID>",
    developerKey: "<KEY>",
    model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
    messages: [
      {
        role: "user",
        content: "Hey ChatGPT, what's the capital of Portugal?",
      },
    ],
  }),
});
const response = await request.json();
```

I tried to solve this on my own with this code.

```py
import requests

url = "https://api.tiktokenizer.dev/openai"
headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer <OPENAI_API_KEY>"}
data = {
    "email": "<APP_USER_EMAIL>",
    "appId": "<APPID>",
    "developerKey": "<KEY>",
    "model": "gpt-3.5-turbo",
    "messages": [
      {
        "role": "user",
        "content": "Hey ChatGPT, what's the capital of Portugal?",
      },
    ],
}

response = requests.post(url=url, headers=headers, json=data)

print(response.json())
```

With the above code I filled in all the needed info but I got this error.

> {'error': 'Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1'}

What should happen is I get something like this back.

```json
{
  message: "The capital of Portugal is Lisbon.",
  usage: {
    totalTokens: 25,
  },
  newUserCreated: false,
}
```

Comment: The JS code uses JSON.stringify, so i wonder if the API doesn't actually accept JSON, but instead accepts a string that _looks like_ JSON...

Comment: Try this `requests.post(url=url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use json.dumps() on the data before sending it to the request.

Working Code

```py
url = "https://api.tiktokenizer.dev/openai"
headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer <OPENAI_API_KEY>"}
data = json.dumps({
    "email": "<EMAIL>",
    "appId": "<APPID>",
    "developerKey": "<KEY>",
    "model": "gpt-3.5-turbo",
    "messages": [
      {
        "role": "user",
        "content": "Hey ChatGPT, what's the capital of Portugal?",
      },
    ],
})

response = requests.post(url=url, headers=headers, json=data)

print(response.json())
```

Returns

```
{'message': 'The capital city of Portugal is Lisbon.', 'usage':{'totalTokensUsed': 27}, 'newUserCreated': False}
```

Answer (score 0):

After the code

```
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data)
```

You can print the raw response if the JSON is not valid.

```
if response.status_code == 200:
    try:
        response_data = response.json()
        print(response_data)
    except json.JSONDecodeError:
        print("Response is not valid JSON:")
        print(response.content)
else:
    print("Error:", response.status_code)
```

This should help you diagnose the issue and understand what the server is returning.

You can then adjust your code accordingly based on the actual response content.

Hope this helps! Happy coding :)

Comment: I put the code in and it gave me this error: "Error: 500"
When I print out the content of the response I get the same error as before.

Comment: The error 500 is a generic response mean that there is an error in the server, maybe a malformed request, not necessarily an error in your code, but in your request or in the server. You should check the documentation and see if everything is all right!